# Need help eliminating white space on top of flexbox page

Tags: html, css, whitespace, flexbox

I'm a new developer learning to design layouts using Flexbox css. I'm having a problem removing white space at the top of the page. I've tried setting the body margin and padding to zero, but that doesn't work. The only thing that seems to work is putting an -18px margin on my wrapper, but that won't solve the problem across different browsers. Any help would be appreciated. Here's my code and css:

HTML Starts Here

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Flexbox Tutorial</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper"> 
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box2">2</div>
  <div class="box box3">3</div>
  <div class="box box4">4</div>
  <div class="box box5">5</div>
  <div class="box box6">6</div>
  <div class="box box7">7</div>
  <div class="box box8">8</div>
  <div class="box box9">9</div>
  <div class="box box10">10</div>
  </div><!--end of wrapper-->

  </body>
  </html>
```

HTML Ends Here

CSS Starts Here

```
    body {margin: 0;
         padding: 0;}

/* Some default styles to make each box visible */
    .box {
        color: white;
        font-size: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        text-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rbga(0,0,0,0.1); 
}
    .box p {
        font-size: 20px; 
}
/* Colours for each box */
    .box1 {background: #1abc9c;}
    .box2 {background: #3498db;}
    .box3 {background: #9b59b6;}
    .box4 {background: #34495e;}
    .box5 {background: #f1c40f;}
    .box6 {background: #e67e22;}
    .box7 {background: #e74c3c;}
    .box8 {background: #bdc3c7;}
    .box9 {background: #2ecc71;}
    .box10 {background: #16a085;}

/* We start writing out flexbox here. */

.wrapper {display: flex;
         flex-direction: row;
}

CSS ends here
```

Comment: I'm running your code in Chrome and there's no whitespace on top the page. Maybe you're missing some code? See if you can post a demo that reproduces the problem. Try using jsfiddle.net.

Comment: have made a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1zjcuhk9/) with your code, it fine imo, maybe you miss something?

Comment: I do not see any white space too at the top ..Do you have any css resets or normalizers on ur page?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help everyone. The code is working fine now. I think the whitespace I was seeing was either being caused by space left between the !doctype html tag and the html lang="en" tag, or a mistake I made with the meta charset="utf-8" tag. I initially had UTF capitalized. Not sure if either of those two things caused the white space, but after I made those two changes, removing the space between the doctype and html tag, and changung UTF to lowercase, the whitespace was gone. Thanks for your help!